# Best practice (UAT) testdata

Tags: bestpractice

I was wondering what your opinions are about UAT testdata in case there's no Full Copy Sandbox available. As far as I'm aware there's two options:

- Developing a testdata factory, which tries to mock data that is as close as possible to production data. This is probably the quicker option, but never entirely representative of the data that is present in production.
- Writing a script that extracts data from production and inserts it into the UAT environment. This might be a bit more cumbersome depending on the dependencies in your data, but seems like the better option when it comes to having an accurate representation of your production data.

Can you tell me your opinion of both options, possible describe other options and/or point me to tools that might be available for mocking testdata? I might've missed something obvious. :-)

Comment: Did you look at Partial Data Sandboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a good resource to loading test data into sandboxes using Ruby: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Generating_and_Loading_Representative_Test_Data_for_Salesforce_and_Force.com_Orgs

If you would rather buy something off the shelf, Informatica's tool comes highly recommended: http://www.informatica.com/us/solutions/application-information-lifecycle-management/test-data-management/#fbid=ebe8eFcnIab

Good luck!